# Arch (or Manjaro) install into KVM VM: UEFI boot disk not found after cold start

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, kvm, uefi, qemu

I installed Arch Linux into a KVM virtual machine using the [Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide). The installation was successful because after rebooting, I boot into my fresh installation. The problem is that after I shut down,I can no longer boot into my new system.[image]

This is my qemu start script. If I uncomment the iso file, I can boot back into the arch iso and chroot into the new install and everything looks fine as far as I can tell.

```
cp /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd /tmp/my_vars_arch.fd

qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name $vmname,process=$vmname \
-machine type=q35,accel=kvm \
-cpu host,topoext \
-smp 12,sockets=1,cores=6,threads=2 \
-m 32G \
-vga qxl \
-spice port=5930,disable-ticketing=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=43:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=43:00.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=0b:00.3 \
-rtc clock=host,base=localtime \
-serial none \
-parallel none \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/tmp/my_vars_arch.fd \
-boot order=dc \
-drive file=/dev/NVME-TANK/ext4-zvol,format=raw,if=virtio \
#-drive file=/home/boss/ISOs/archlinux-2022.03.01-x86_64.iso,index=1,media=cdrom \
-nic bridge,br=br0,model=virtio-net-pci
```

Edit: after installing Arch via the guide, I installed efibootmgr and bootloader according to [These instructions](https://itsfoss.com/install-arch-linux/)

The paths I have specified for OVMF firmware are fine in that they work for other VMs.

I am able to boot directly into the system again by following [these instructions](https://mricher.fr/post/boot-from-an-efi-shell/), but I am still not sure what I need to check or do to make this happen by default. I think I installed grub and created `grub.cfg` correctly by doing:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --recheck
```

and then

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I re-ran the above two commands after chrooting into the system, looks ok right?
[image: os-prober isn't needed for uefi, is it?]

What am I missing?

One other detail, not sure if it is relevant: If I comment out all my passthrough devices, I get a different screen:

And one more: I installed Manjaro using a minimal live iso, and the same thing happened! Rebooted into the new install, but after shutting down, booted to the uefi shell.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you have generated the fstab file.

Read the part about Initramfs, if needed adjust and regenerate.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide#Fstab

---

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU#VM_does_not_boot_when_using_a_Secure_Boot_enabled_OVMF

This was the Problem, adding those flags to the ISO solved it.
See comments.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I did generate fstab and `mkinitcpio -P` ran without errors.

Comment: Could this be relevant?
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU#VM_does_not_boot_when_using_a_Secure_Boot_enabled_OVMF

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen that. Unfortunately adding `-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1` to my qemu command did not help.

Comment: Update: I tried again, but this time I used `-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1` for booting the install ISO (instead of adding it post-install). I now can boot into my installation from the VM after a full shutdown. Not sure why I had to have it there from the get-go, but thank you!!!

Comment: Actually it seems I spoke to soon. This worked with the Manjaro installer, but Arch is still having the same problem. I just assumed if it fixed in in MJ it would fix it in Arch too. Still leaving it marked as "answered" because it did work for Manjaro.